# Passing Anonymous Type to a Bound Control

Tags: c#

Generally speaking, I'm fairly opposed to the use of anonymous types in real-world code (except in LINQ and some other specific scenarios), but I'm looking right now at a situation where I need to bind an ASP `GridView` control with a collection of tuple values and they're looking pretty tempting.

Basically, I need to show a list of proprietary accounts that are associated with different computer names. I don't currently have a type that contains those two properties because I don't use them together like this anywhere else.

What I would normally do in a situation like this is just create a new class that has the properties, set the `ItemType` on the `GridView` to reference that type, then build objects of that type in my `Select` method (I use `ObjectDataSource` much of the time). But I'm thinking now that there's really no benefit to throwing in that extra class, since no matter what it's getting bound via reflection.

**Is there any reason to shy away from using anonymous types in data-binding situations like this?**

I'd accept anything: performance, readability, maintainability, principle, or whatever else you can throw at me. But the only disadvantage I can think of is if I wanted to use the `Item` property to use Intellisense for my data-binding, but in this particular case I have no use for anything more than `BoundField`s. Of course, this is all based on the assumption that it even works, admittedly I haven't tried it yet with anonymous types, so it might just not be supported for one reason or another.

Comment: > But I'm thinking now that there's really no benefit to throwing in that extra class, since no matter what it's getting bound via reflection. you are asking wrong question. what is the benefits of using dynamic types other static **in this situation**? Anything comes to mind? no? because there are none. your 'argument' above is not valid. binding via reflection is the only way to bind something and is irrelevant to dynamic/static argument you are trying to induce.

Comment: What are the benefits of using anonymous types? I don't have to bother with writing and instantiating a class that I'll only ever use once. It isn't *really* a big deal to make one, but that's why I'm asking this question here and not on SO. It works either way, I'm just wondering whether there are any reasons I should put in the extra effort to write a class with two string properties.

Comment: As for my point about binding via reflection, yes, I know that's the only way to bind something. That *is* my point. Since it'll be done by reflection one way or the other, what benefit does bothering to add in a class actually give me? Generally it'd be strong-typing and speed, but that's not relevant when dealing with a `BoundField` that uses a `string` to know which property it should reflect.

Comment: I was under the impression that dynamic/anonymous types are still strongly typed by the time you get to runtime?

Comment: @Ewan Bad choice of words, sorry about that. What I really meant was that using `Item` would give me compile-time checking for properties I called. But I wouldn't get those with the `BoundField` attribute either way, hence why it wasn't a big concern. Yes, the compiler generates types for them, there's just no way (that I know of) to tell the designer to expect that dynamic type.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

And your assumption about it not being statically typed is wrong too.

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object. The compiler provides a name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access it. From the perspective of the common language runtime, an anonymous type is no different from any other reference type.